# Resource ID:- Displaying Resources Id #14 not actual database value on existing pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, while-loop, fpdf

HERE is my code, can anybody help me with this? The output is displaying in pdf but displays values like `Resource id #14` in existing pdf template.

The Reason is due this($pdf->Write(73, "".$result);) line it Printing resource id#14

If I put `$myrow` instead if `$result` it displays nothing in pdf so what to do please anybody help me I have kept it on button click to generate PDF and also to solve FPDF error: `Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file`

and I have not put anything in while loop to solve same above error

From here my code starts

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['btn_NEXT'])) {  

     mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
     ini_set('display_errors', true);

     include('/Fpdf(1.7)Extracted/fpdf.php');
     include('/Fpdi(1.6)Extracted/fpdi.php');

     $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die('Error');
     mysql_select_db('DbName');

     $pdf =& new FPDI(); 
     // add a page 
     $pdf->AddPage(); 
     // set the sourcefile 
     $pdf->setSourceFile('Demo_Marathi2.pdf'); 
     // import page 1 
     $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
     // use the imported page as the template 

     $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 

     $cmd = "select * from Demo_hindi";
     $result = mysql_query($cmd);
     while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     }
    //$pdf->Text(105, 73, $myrow['DemoHindi']['demo_Values']);
    //$pdf->Text(105, 73,$result);

    //$pdf->Write(65,$myrow['DemoHindi']);
    //$pdf->Write(73,$myrow['demo_Values']);

    $pdf->Write(73, "".$result);
    echo"".$pdf->Output('newpdf.pdf', 'D');

   //PDF CREATION CODE enchant_dict_suggest(dict, word)
   ob_end_clean();
}
```

Comment: In this case `$result` is the result from the mysql query so it is a resource. The call to write the output to the pdf ~ `$pdf->write(73,$result);` is probably working correctly, you need to iterate through the recordset and write the results.

Answer (score 0):

I must stress that this is a guess as I have never seen these classes ( FPDF, FPDI )

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['btn_NEXT'])) {  

     mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
     ini_set('display_errors', true);

     include('/Fpdf(1.7)Extracted/fpdf.php');
     include('/Fpdi(1.6)Extracted/fpdi.php');

     $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die('Error');
     mysql_select_db('DbName');

     $pdf =& new FPDI(); 
     // add a page 
     $pdf->AddPage(); 
     // set the sourcefile 
     $pdf->setSourceFile('Demo_Marathi2.pdf'); 
     // import page 1 
     $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
     // use the imported page as the template 

     $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 

     $cmd = "select * from Demo_hindi";
     $result = mysql_query($cmd);
     while( $myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

        /* This is where you need to fetch the data and write the output */
        /* I don't know what the method `Text` does so this is a guess */

        $pdf->Write(65, $pdf->Text(105, 73, $myrow['DemoHindi'] ) );
        $pdf->Write(73, $pdf->Text(105, 73, $myrow['demo_Values'] ));
     }



    echo"".$pdf->Output('newpdf.pdf', 'D');

   //PDF CREATION CODE enchant_dict_suggest(dict, word)
   ob_end_clean();
}

?>
```